# Change CSS display to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, toggle

I got this code on my page:

HTML:

```
<table class="position2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody><tr valign="top">
          <td class="my-width">  <div class="region region-top1">
    <div class="block block-menu" id="block-menu-menu-drugie-menu-testowe">
<div class="art-block clearfix">
        <div class="art-blockheader"><h3 class="t subject">
  Moje kursy</h3>
</div>        <div class="art-blockcontent"><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/?q=node" title="">Test</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/?q=node" title="">test2</a></li>
</ul></div>
</div></div>
  </div>
</td>
          <td class="my-width">  <div class="region region-top2">
    <div class="block block-menu" id="block-menu-menu-menu-testowe">
<div class="art-block clearfix">
        <div class="art-blockheader"><h3 class="t subject">
  Marketing</h3>
</div>        <div class="art-blockcontent"><ul class="menu"><li class="first collapsed"><a href="/?q=node" title="">Link testowy</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="http://drupal.org" title="">Link2</a></li>
</ul></div>
</div></div>
  </div>
</td>
          <td class="my-width">  <div class="region region-top3">
    <div class="block block-menu" id="block-menu-menu-menu-top3">
<div class="art-block clearfix">
        <div class="art-blockheader"><h3 class="t subject">
  BHP</h3>
</div>        <div class="art-blockcontent"><ul class="menu"><li class="first last leaf"><a href="/?q=node" title="">Link testowy</a></li>
</ul></div>
</div></div>
  </div>
</td>
          <td class="my-width">  <div class="region region-top4">
    <div class="block block-menu" id="block-menu-menu-menu-top4">
<div class="art-block clearfix">
        <div class="art-blockheader"><h3 class="t subject">
  Zarządzanie</h3>
</div>        <div class="art-blockcontent"><ul class="menu"><li class="first last leaf"><a href="/?q=node" title="">Link testowy</a></li>
</ul></div>
</div></div>
  </div>
</td>
          <td class="my-width">  <div class="region region-top5">
    <div class="block block-menu" id="block-menu-menu-menu-top5">
<div class="art-block clearfix">
        <div class="art-blockheader"><h3 class="t subject">
  E-learning</h3>
</div>        <div class="art-blockcontent"><ul class="menu"><li class="first last leaf"><a href="/?q=node" title="">Link testowy</a></li>
</ul></div>
</div></div>
  </div>
</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
```

And simple hide art-blockcontent div with css:hover

```
.position2 .art-blockcontent {
    display: none;
}

.position2:hover .art-blockcontent {
    display: block;
}
```

And i need to convert it to javascript on click. On click show, next click hide.

I tried this:

```
$(".position2").click(function () {
$(".art-blockcontent").toggle("slow");
});
```

But it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have jQuery script loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have to do, TEST YOUR JQUERY WORK

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('JQUERY!')
    $('.position2').click(function () {
          alert('YES!');
    });
});
```

*So click your `.postion2` element, if its work so....*

Use [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) or [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) or [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) *(with your CSS)* or [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
   $('.position2').click(function () {
      $('.art-blockcontent', this).hide();
    });
```

or

```
   $('.position2').click(function () {
      $('.art-blockcontent', this).fadeOut();
   });
```

**To show and hide, do like...**

```
   $('.position2').click(function () {
      $('.art-blockcontent', this).toggle('slow');
   });
```

or

```
   $('.position2').toggle(function(){
     $('.art-blockcontent', this).hide();
   },function(){
     $('.art-blockcontent', this).show();
   });
```

Comment: You all have right, thanks guys for your help. 

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('JQUERY!')
        $('.position2').click(function () {
              alert('YES!');
        });
    });

I thought, that my js file was added to page, I have loaded jquery 1.4.4, so I don't know why it doesn't work for me. I added v1.10.1 above the code and it works. It's very good idea, to check 1st, that test jQuery. I will remember.

Thanks for fast answers and for help. Now all work

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working , try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZjVb/)** , check if jquery is loaded,may be this is your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".position2").click(function () {
    $('.art-blockcontent').toggle();
   });
});
```

Comment: toggle doesn't exist in jquery 1.4 , thats why